# 1st day on extracting the xml file from SQLServer, have Qs about 'PATH'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm reading a SQL fundamental textbook, and below is the T-SQL code:

```
SELECT Customer.custid AS [@custid],
Customer.companyname AS [companyname]
FROM Sales.Customers AS Customer
WHERE Customer.custid <= 2
ORDER BY Customer.custid
FOR XML PATH ('Customer'), ROOT('Customers');
```

Can anybody tell me the point of using PATH, and why there is an @ before custid?

Any suggestions are welcomed, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` marks the column as being an XML attribute instead of an element- ie: you'll get

```
<Customers>
    <Customer custid="1234">
        <companyname>Acme Sprockets Inc</companyname>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

If you take the `@` away, you'd get

```
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <custid>1234</custid>
        <companyname>Acme Sprockets Inc</companyname>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Path allows you to customise the XML structures, without having to resort to `FOR XML EXPLICIT`

I'd start with the documentation online : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx